# Which concepts and techniques do I need to achieve this kind of graph

Tags: d3.js, graph-theory

I want to draw a dynamic visual of how certain functional blocks interact with each other. I'm having difficulty defining what kind of graph I need, and what (if any) d3 layout function is best suited to start with. I'm not even sure my example falls within the definition of a graph.

[image: Rough concept of what I try to achieve]

The general idea is to visualize a group of functions with their inputs and outputs. It starts with a set of inputs, and ends with a set of outputs. In between there are several functions who each take inputs and generate 1 or more outputs. Each output can serve as input for one or more functions. So each edge/line represents an output being transferred to a function to serve as input (and is uni-directional)

I'm not looking for answer in code, but rather an insight on which concepts I need to start with. The image probably has issues and can't be achieved literally, but I can't point out what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const nodes = [
 {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Function A',
  x: 100,
  y: 25,
  points: [
   {
    id: 11,
    dx: 50,
    dy: 0
   },
   {
    id: 12,
    dx: 0,
    dy: 20
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  title: 'Function B',
  x: 300,
  y: 100,
  points: [
   {
    id: 21,
    dx: -50,
    dy: 0
   },
   {
    id: 22,
    dx: 0,
    dy: 20
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  title: 'Function C',
  x: 170,
  y: 160,
  points: [
   {
    id: 31,
    dx: 0,
    dy: -20
   },
   {
    id: 32,
    dx: 50,
    dy: 0
   }
  ]
 }
];

const links = [
 {source: 11, target:21},
 {source: 12, target:31},
 {source: 22, target:32}
];

var selectedNode = null;

const renderNodes = svg => {
 const allNodes = svg.selectAll('.node').data(nodes, node => node.id);
 const addedNodes = allNodes.enter()
  .append('g')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
  .on('click', d => {
   selectedNode = d.id;
   renderAll();
  });
  
 addedNodes.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 40)
  .attr('x', -50)
  .attr('y', -20)
  .attr('rx', 5);

 addedNodes.append('text')
  .text(d => d.title)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .attr('y', 6)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
  
 addedNodes.merge(allNodes)
  .select('rect')
  .style('fill', d => (d.id === selectedNode) ? 'blue' : 'black');
  
 allNodes.exit().remove(); 
};

const renderConnectionPoints = (svg, points) => {
 const allPoints = svg.selectAll('.point').data(points, point => point.id);
 const addedPoints = allPoints.enter()
  .append('g')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
  
 addedPoints.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 4)
  .style('fill', 'white');

 addedPoints.merge(allPoints)
  .select('circle')
  .style('stroke', d => (d.parentId === selectedNode) ? 'blue' : 'black');
  
 allPoints.exit().remove(); 
}

const renderLinks = (svg, _links) => {
 const linkPath = d => `M ${d.source.x}, ${d.source.y} 
  C ${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2}, ${d.source.y}
  ${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2}, ${d.target.y}
  ${d.target.x}, ${d.target.y}`;

 const allLinks = svg.selectAll('.link').data(_links, link => link.id);
 const addedLinks = allLinks.enter()
  .append('path')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .attr('d', linkPath);
  
 addedLinks.merge(allLinks)
  .style('stroke', d => (d.source.parentId === selectedNode || 
  d.target.parentId === selectedNode) ? 'blue' : 'lightgray');
  
 allLinks.exit().remove(); 
 
}

const getPoints = () => nodes.reduce((all, node) => {
  node.points.forEach(point => all.push({
   id: point.id, x: node.x + point.dx, y: node.y + point.dy, parentId: node.id}));
  return all;
 }, []);

const getLinks = points => links.map(link => {
  const source = points.find(point => point.id === link.source);
  const target = points.find(point => point.id === link.target);
  return {source, target};
 });  

const renderAll = () => {
 const svg = d3.select('svg');
 const points = getPoints();
 const _links = getLinks(points);
 renderNodes(svg);
 renderLinks(svg, _links);
 renderConnectionPoints(svg, points);
} 

renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='400' height='180'>
 
</svg>
```

Hi,
Take a look at the snippet.
The data model is very simple: nodes, their connection points and links
Just provide your data and use the snippet's code to render it.
Good luck and feel free to ask any question :)

Comment: This is cool, thank you! The real difficulty however is getting the coordinates to position the 'functions'. The raw data will not have any positioning data. The nodes and lines are easy since they directly relate to the edges of a function rectangle. However, the functions should be able to auto-position themself like the many 'd3 hiarchy' of "d3-force" examples you find online. How is that done? Where do I start to write my own logic?

Comment: The type of graph you deal with is not a hierarchical one (direct hierarchy cannot have loops). The force layout can be useful but might be difficult to modify. I suggest to implement your own simple layout by putting items in rows and columns.

Answer (score -1):

sorry by my bad english, I speak spanish...
I also look for something similar, researching I have achieved this, and I am missing:

- Transform nodes circles into rectangles
- Add text labels to each node and each link
- Once everything is organized initially, they remain in a fixed location
- Capture the click on each node and / or link to trigger another application

I leave the code below, observe especially the definition of nodes_data and links_data, and functions to define size and color:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: black ;
  stroke-width: 0px;
}

</style>
<svg width="1000" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

//create somewhere to put the force directed graph
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

//var radius = 15; 

var nodes_data =  [
    {"name": "PO1", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PO2", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PO3", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PO4", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PO5", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PO6", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PO7", "entity": "PO"},
    {"name": "PY1", "entity": "PY"},
    {"name": "PY2", "entity": "PY"},
    {"name": "L1", "entity": "X"},
    {"name": "L2", "entity": "X"},
    {"name": "L3", "entity": "X"},
    {"name": "L4", "entity": "X"},
    {"name": "TK1", "entity": "TK"},
    {"name": "TK2", "entity": "TK"},
    {"name": "PIL1", "entity": "TK"},
    {"name": "BBA1", "entity": "BA"},
    {"name": "BBA2", "entity": "BA"},
    {"name": "ULAC1", "entity": "UL"},
    {"name": "VtaYPF", "entity": "VTA"}
    ]

//Sample links data 
//type: A for Ally, E for Enemy
var links_data = [
    {"source": "PO1", "target": "L1", "type":"A" },
    {"source": "PO2", "target": "L1", "type":"A" },
    {"source": "PO3", "target": "L1", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PO4", "target": "L2", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PO5", "target": "L2", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PO6", "target": "L3", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PO7", "target": "L3", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "L1", "target": "L3", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "L2", "target": "L3", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "L3", "target": "TK1", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "L3", "target": "TK2", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "TK1", "target": "L4", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "TK2", "target": "L4", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "L4", "target": "PIL1", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PIL1", "target": "ULAC1", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PIL1", "target": "BBA1", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "PIL1", "target": "BBA2", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "ULAC1", "target": "VtaYPF", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "BBA1", "target": "PY1", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "BBA2", "target": "PY2", "type":"A"}

]


//set up the simulation and add forces  
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                    .nodes(nodes_data);

var link_force =  d3.forceLink(links_data)
                        .id(function(d) { return d.name; });            

var charge_force = d3.forceManyBody()
    .strength(-100); 

var center_force = d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2);  

simulation
    .force("charge_force", charge_force)
    .force("center_force", center_force)
    .force("links",link_force)
 ;


//add tick instructions: 
simulation.on("tick", tickActions );

//add encompassing group for the zoom 
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "everything");

//draw lines for the links 
var link = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links_data)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("stroke", linkColour);        

//draw circles for the nodes 
var node = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes") 
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("fill", circleColour);


//add drag capabilities  
var drag_handler = d3.drag()
    .on("start", drag_start)
    .on("drag", drag_drag)
    .on("end", drag_end);   

drag_handler(node);


//add zoom capabilities 
var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

zoom_handler(svg);     

/** Functions **/

//Function to choose what color circle we have
//Let's return blue for males and red for females
function circleColour(d){
   var my_color
   switch (d.entity) {
    case "PO": my_color = "black";  break;
    case "PY": my_color = "cyan";   break;
    case "TK": my_color = "blue";   break;
    case "UL": my_color = "green";  break;
    case "VTA": my_color = "green"; break;
    case "BA": my_color = "cyan";   break;
    case "X": my_color = "grey";    break;
    }
   return my_color
}

//Function to choose the line colour and thickness 
//If the link type is "A" return green 
//If the link type is "E" return red 
function linkColour(d){
    if(d.type == "A"){
        return "green";
    } else {
        return "red";
    }
}

//Drag functions 
//d is the node 
function drag_start(d) {
 if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

//make sure you can't drag the circle outside the box
function drag_drag(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function drag_end(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

//Zoom functions 
function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

function tickActions() {
    //update circle positions each tick of the simulation 
       node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    //update link positions 
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
} 

function radius(d){
  var my_rad
   switch (d.entity) {
    case "PO": my_rad = 10; break;
    case "PY": my_rad = 10; break;
    case "TK": my_rad = 20; break;
    case "UL": my_rad = 20; break;
    case "VTA": my_rad = 15;    break;
    case "BA": my_rad = 10; break;
    case "X": my_rad = 3;   break;
    }
   return my_rad
}
</script>
```

[The above code generate this live image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ulP.png)